# how to save a collection of items( subjects ) into a list and save in a database

Tags: php, laravel

i have created student and subject models and their CRUD
how do i register a collection of subject_id for a student

i have created a new model 'Registration' with subject_id and student_id but i don't how to add a collection of subject_id's to students

This is my student model

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    protected $fillable = [
            'firstname','middlename','lastname','index_no','parent_id',
            'regular_or_weekend',
            'course_id',
            'nationality',
            'image'
      ]

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
    }
}
```

this is my subject class

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subjects';

    protected $fillable = ['subject_code','subject_name','credit_hours'];

    protected $cast =[
        'credit_hours' => 'Integer',
    ];

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, this is what you need: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @nakov is correct - Laravel uses conventions for the name of the relationship - you'll need to add those to your DB and `fillable`. (Or override).  But the docs will explain.

Comment: The subjects in this hypothetical collection are already saved in the database or are all new objects? BTW you didn't give me any feedback, accept or upvote on my answer to your question on regexp so I decide to answer no more to your questions. Bye @eons.

Comment: sorry @dparoli . it will never happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In has many relationships you should do something like this:

```
$student = Student::find(1);

$student->subjects()->createMany([
    [
        'subject_code' => 'code',
        'subject_name' => 'name',
        'credit_hours' => 'hours'
    ],
    [
         'subject_code' => 'code',
        'subject_name' => 'name',
        'credit_hours' => 'hours'
    ],
]);
```